# Android ListView slide animation when item is selected

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this ListView:

```
    @Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSpinner.clearAnimation();
                }
                });

            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                //profile.getInstalled();
                values.add(profile.getName());
            }



            ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_items2, values);
            friendsListAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);    
                }
            });
            mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsListAdapter);
        }
    };
```

And in xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
    android:divider="#8A8A8A"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.9dp"
    android:listSelector="#ccc"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

</ListView>
```

I have tried looking for solutions for this or similar effects but i couldn't really find any helpul ones.

The ListView loads friends from facebook, when a friend is selected in the ListView, what it does now is that it changes the selected item to a grey color, but what i would want it to do is to create a "sliding" animation, with the color. Like this:

Here is ListView before the item is selected:

[image: Here is listview before item is selected:]

When the item has been selected, the color slides in from right to left:

[image]

And when finished it should look something like this:

[image]

How could i create this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Android Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html). One approach would be to create a Bitmap of the `View` the user selected and put it in front of the row of your `ListView`, then start painting it with the color you want from left to right. When you finished painting it change the row background color and delete the Bitmap.

To paint a single row you will have to create some kind of map in your adapter and track what `Views` you have to paint with a background color in your on `getView()` method of the adapter.

A similar approach is used [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q%20%22%22) to reorder a `ListView`.